# Unknown Mitsubishi automotive MCUs - are these using unknown architecture?

Tags: binary-analysis, ghidra, radare2, binwalk

Please help ientify the architecture (ISA) of [MH8200F](https://www.autoelectric.by/images/Mitsubishi/Carisma_MH8200F/Carisma_MH8200F_2.JPG) and MH8110F <sup>*which is found almost exclusively on Mazda ECUs with L3CK, L587, L5E8, LFAR, LFFR, LFJP firmwares*</sup>

I've revealed that the [MH8501F](https://a.d-cd.net/20xj0W41NJ-hqimunNWQBsZDS-U-960.jpg) is obviously the re-labelled SH72543 of which belongs to the SuperH family of MCUs...

And also help identify MH86xx MCUs from much newer models of Mitsubishi cars...